# COBOL output not changing. Trouble seeing output with notepad.

Tags: cobol

I am trying to see the output for this program I am working on. I was instructed to use notepad but every time I open the file I get the old output I had before making changes to it. I don't know if this is a programming error or a technical flub on my part. Could you guys take a look and see whats up?

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. CH0402Practice.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT PAYROLL-MASTER
           ASSIGN TO "C0402.DAT"
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT PRINT-FILE
           ASSIGN TO "C0402.RPT".
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  PAYROLL-MASTER
       LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD
       RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS
       BLOCK CONTAINS 20 RECORDS.
   01  MASTER-REC.
       05  EMP-NO-IN                       PIC X(5).
       05  NAME-IN                         PIC X(20).
       05  LOC-CODE-IN.
           10  TERR-NO-IN                  PIC XX.
           10  OFFICE-NO-IN                PIC XX.
       05  SALARY-IN                       PIC 9(6).
       05  SS-NO-IN                        PIC 9(9).
       05  DEP-IN                          PIC 99.
       05  JOB-CLASS-IN                    PIC 99.
       05                                  PIC X(32).
   FD  PRINT-FILE
       LABEL RECORDS ARE OMITTED
       RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS.
   01  REPORT-OUT                          PIC X(80).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS              PIC XXX.
   01  HEADING-LINE1.
       05                                  PIC X(33)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(15)  VALUE
           "PAYROLL LISTING".
       05                                  PIC X(32)  VALUE SPACES.

   01  HEADING-LINE2.
       05                                  PIC X(5)   VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(10)  VALUE
           "EMP NUMBER".
       05                                  PIC X(4)   VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(4)   VALUE
           "NAME".
       05                                  PIC X(16) VALUE
           "SALARY".
       05                                  PIC X(7)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(5)  VALUE
           "SS NO".
       05                                  PIC X(9)  VALUE
           "DEPENDENT".
       05                                  PIC X(25) VALUE SPACES.
   01  DETAIL-LINE.
       05                                  PIC X(5).
       05  EMP-NO-OUT                      PIC X(5).
       05                                  PIC X(14).
       05  NAME-OUT                        PIC X(20).
       05                                  PIC X(4).
       05  SALARY-OUT                      PIC 9(6).
       05                                  PIC X(7).
       05  SS-NO-OUT                       PIC 9(9).
       05                                  PIC X(7).
       05  DEP-OUT                         PIC 99.
       05                                  PIC X(21).



   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN-MODULE.
       PERFORM 100-INITIALIZATION-MODULE.
       PERFORM 200-PRINT-MODULE
            UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO '.
       CLOSE PAYROLL-MASTER
             PRINT-FILE.
       STOP RUN.
   100-INITIALIZATION-MODULE.
       OPEN INPUT  PAYROLL-MASTER
            OUTPUT PRINT-FILE.
       MOVE 'YES' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS.
       PERFORM 300-TOP-OF-PAGE-MODULE.
       PERFORM 600-READ-MODULE.
   200-PRINT-MODULE.
       MOVE SPACES TO REPORT-OUT.
       MOVE EMP-NO-IN TO EMP-NO-OUT.
       MOVE NAME-IN TO NAME-OUT.
       MOVE SALARY-IN TO SALARY-OUT.
       MOVE SS-NO-IN TO SS-NO-OUT.
       MOVE DEP-IN TO DEP-OUT.
       MOVE DETAIL-LINE TO REPORT-OUT.
       WRITE REPORT-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINES.
       PERFORM 600-READ-MODULE.

   300-TOP-OF-PAGE-MODULE.
       MOVE HEADING-LINE1 TO REPORT-OUT.
       WRITE REPORT-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINES.
       MOVE SPACES TO REPORT-OUT.
       WRITE REPORT-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINES.
       MOVE HEADING-LINE2 TO REPORT-OUT.
       WRITE REPORT-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINES.

   600-READ-MODULE.
       READ PAYROLL-MASTER
            AT END MOVE 'NO ' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
       END-READ.
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you don't have the output file open when your run your program again.  Also, find a better text editor such as Notepad++ to use.

Answer (score 1):

The usual suspects are

1. You didn't change what you thought that you changed in the program.
2. You didn't recompile the program before running it again so you ended up running the old version of the program which, of course, produced the same results.
3. You ran the program from a different folder which put the new output file somethere other that you thought it was so you aren't really looking at the new output file.

Answer (score 0):

Delete or rename the "old" file to be sure. 
You can add "eyecatcher" writes to verify.
If the file timestamp is changing but the output is not you are running an older version.
Have you changed the file name in the code but are checking the old name ?